# Extended Pythagorean Theorem

Tags: geometry, pythagorean-triples

Extended Pythagorean Theorem 
We all well familiar with the basic Pythagorean statement – I will use a different description that will serve the discussion that follows –
Given two points in $2D$ space, $(a,0)$ and $(0,b)$ with distance $d$ between them, than the relation between $a, b,$ and $d$ follows

$a^2+b^2=d^2$

In $3D$ this is extended to three points $(a,0,0)$, $(0,b,0)$ and $(0,0,c)$ with an area of $s$ for the triangle created by the three points - than the following equation holds:

$^1/_4(a^2+b^2+c^2)=s^2$

I wonder if this is true for higher dimensions, as example $4D$ - given four points $(a,0,0,0)$, $(0,b,0,0)$, $(0,0,c,0)$, $(0,0,0,d)$ and the volume for the pyramid created by the four point to be $v$ than

$^1/_9(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)=v^2$ ???

Comment: If you want to try checking your conjecture yourself, you might be interested in the [Cayley-Menger determinant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cayley-MengerDeterminant.html).

Comment: @JM Thanks for the link but it seems he is tackling a different problem.

Comment: Well, you can take your points pairwise, get their distances, and plug them into the determinant, no?

Comment: I made an edit - the relation is different as you may see now - in 2D we deal with triangles and in 4D with pyramids... there is no pairwise action, as I see it, that can be helpful

Comment: For $4$-dimension, the relation should be 
$(\frac{abc}{3!})^2 +
(\frac{bcd}{3!})^2 +
(\frac{cda}{3!})^2 +
(\frac{dab}{3!})^2 = v^2$. The correct generalization is known as [De Gua's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Gua's_theorem).

Comment: Consider a pentachoron in 5 dimensions; you have five points, and $\binom{5}{2}$ pairs of points corresponding to the line segments joining them. You now have $10$ entries to fill into the determinant (symmetry takes care of the rest.)

Comment: Could not edit this one properly! Posted another one.

Comment: @achille Are you sure about the $3!$ - it is not the pyramids volume as I expect.. thanks for the insight!

Comment: You can construct Pythagorean n-tuples of any dimension using techniques described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3238431/edit). I'm not sure about the $\frac{1}{x}$ thing in your question but I the Ellingson equations [linked] can give you the tuples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As achille hui pointed out in a comment, the relevant generalization here would be [De Gua's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Gua's_theorem) for three dimensions or the [Conant–Beyer theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem#Sets_of_m-dimensional_objects_in_n-dimensional_space) for arbitrary dimensions. Colloquially speaking it states that the squared measure of your object equals the sum of the squared measures of its projection on a set of mutually orthogonal hyperplanes, in your case the coordinate axes.

So let's look at this in the dimensions we know. A segment from $(a,0)$ to $(0,b)$ has some length $d$ as measure. Projecting the segment onto the $x$ axis yields a segment of length $a$, projecting onto the $y$ axis yields a segment of length $b$. So taken together you have $d^2 = a^2 + b^2$ as expected.

In three dimensions, you have a triangle, and project that onto the coordinate planes. But here the area of the projection is a triangle, not a rectangle, so you don't simply multiply the intercepts, but divide by $2$ as the area of a right triangle is $\frac12 ab$. Thus the area is

$$s^2 =
\biggl(\frac{ab}2\biggr)^2 +
\biggl(\frac{ac}2\biggr)^2 +
\biggl(\frac{bc}2\biggr)^2 =
\frac{a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2}{4}
$$

This differs from the $s^2=\frac14\left(a^2+b^2+c^2\right)$ you claimed here originally, but fits in with the $s^2=\frac14((ab)^2+(bc)^2+(ac)^2)$ you wrote in the [duplicate post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2075228/35416).

For four dimensions, you have to turn the volume of the cuboid into the volume of the simplex spanned by three of its edges. The factor to divide by here is $6$, so the formula for the volume will be

$$v^2 =
\biggl(\frac{abc}6\biggr)^2 +
\biggl(\frac{abd}6\biggr)^2 +
\biggl(\frac{acd}6\biggr)^2 +
\biggl(\frac{bcd}6\biggr)^2$$

So where you assumed the denominator to be $9$, it is in fact $6^2=36$. That $6$ there in the denominator is the $3!$ achille hui wrote in the comment, which is a more useful notation because it also explains how you get the corresponding factor for arbitrary dimensions. You might think of the area of the simplex as $\frac13$ times base plane times hright, where the base plane is again $\frac12$ times one length times the other. If you go to $d$ dimensions, you take all ways of combining $d-1$ of the $d$ edge lengths, multiply them and divide them by $(d-1)!$. The resulting numbers get squared and added.
If you want a general formula for arbitrary dimensions, you could write something like

$$v^2=\sum_{i=1}^d\left(\begin{array}{c}
\displaystyle\prod_{\substack{j=1\\j\neq i}}^{d}x_j
\\\hline(d-1)!\end{array}\right)^2$$

This is for the simplex spanned by $(x_1,0,\dots,0)$ through $(0,\dots,0,x_d)$.